# Issue properly implementing interpolation search in java?

Tags: java, search, interpolation

I have to implement an interpolation search in my program to see if a value entered by the user is part of the array and if it is it should return what position in the array it is in. Right now when I search for a value in the array it simply returns the the number you searched for rounded down, and is stuck in an infinite loop.

```html
public static void  interpolationSearch(double searchValue, double[] array) {
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = array.length - 1;
        double dvLowerBound = array[lowerBound];
        double dvUpperBound = array[upperBound];
        int splitPosition;

        while (searchValue >= dvLowerBound && searchValue <= dvUpperBound) {
            splitPosition = (int) (lowerBound + ((searchValue - dvLowerBound) / 
                    (dvUpperBound - dvLowerBound)) * (upperBound - lowerBound));

            if (array[splitPosition] < searchValue) {
                lowerBound = splitPosition + 1;
            } else if (array[splitPosition] > searchValue) {
                upperBound = splitPosition - 1;
            } else 
                System.out.println((int) array[splitPosition]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> the number you searched for rounded down

This happens because your code is explicitly casting the `double` to `int`:

```
System.out.println((int) array[splitPosition]);
                   ^^^^^
```

> and is stuck in an infinite loop

You need to stop the loop once you've found the number, for example by using `break`:

```
        if (array[splitPosition] < searchValue) {
            ...
        } else if (array[splitPosition] > searchValue) {
            ...
        } else {
            System.out.println(...);
            break;
        }
```